# ImageMagick V7 and Trimming Tool for Multiple Images

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, imagemagick, trim

I am trying to trim multiple images in a folder using ImageMagick V7 on Linux CentOS 7 via this command-line:

```
magick mogrify -trim +repage -path /projectnb/burbsp/home/ialalawi/research/idl/Auroral_Image_Plots/Gill/Clear_No_Aurora/2011-01-14-01 *.png
```

And I get this error:

> mogrify: unable to open image '*.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695.
>   mogrify: unable to open file `*.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3983.

I just followed the format given on the ImageMagick webpage. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a Stack Overflow problem because it involves the use of ImageMagick --> a command-line image visualization tool (software tool + shell interface).

Comment: The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) details what is on-topic and off-topic. In particular, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Your command works fine for me on IM 7.0.8.60 Q16 Mac OSX. My best guess is that your install does not include libpng. What do you get from `magick -version`? Other possibility is that you have not changed directory to the directory holding the images or your -path directory is not correct for where you want your output image to go.

Comment: Maybe you have inadvertently created a file called `.png` - maybe try removing it with `rm .png`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your command works fine for me on IM 7.0.8.60 Q16 Mac OSX.

This is what I did to test it.

```
I created two new directories on my desktop, test1 and test2.

Then I did 

cd desktop/test1

magick rose: -bordercolor white -border 50 rose1.png
magick rose: -bordercolor white -border 50 rose2.png
magick rose: -bordercolor white -border 50 rose3.png

Then I used your command to successfully process the image in test1 and put the output in test2

magick mogrify -trim +repage -path ../test2 *.png
```

My best guess is that your install does not include libpng. What do you get from `magick -version`? Other possibilities are that you have not changed directory to the directory holding the input images or your -path directory is not correct for where you want your output images to go.

You might also try adding -format png to your command line.

Try repeating my command, if your IM 7 version shows PNG listed under delegates. Be sure to change directories to where your input images resize and check the spelling of your path to where you want the output images.

Refer to [here](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify) for details on mogrify.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I realized the issue is with the working directory itself. I didn't realize I have to change to the directory that includes the images to use the command-line!